# How to properly pass an array of values to the `attr_accessible` method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, attr-accessible

I am using Ruby on Rails v3.2.2 and I would like to handle an *array of symbols* so to pass its values to the `attr_accessible` method as well as it should be made. That is, I have:

```
attr_array = [:one, :two, ...]
```

If I use:

```
attr_accessible attr_array
```

I get the following:

```
self.accessible_attributes.inspect
# => #<ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::WhiteList: {"[:one, :two, ..."]}>
```

However, I would like to get:

```
# => #<ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::WhiteList: {"one", "two", "..."}>
```

as well as it should be made.

How can I make that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just like this :

```
attr_accessible *array
```

Comment: @thoferon - Thanks... but, how is called the `*` prefix in the Ruby language?

Comment: Here is a cool post on the splat operator: http://endofline.wordpress.com/2011/01/21/the-strange-ruby-splat/